# Как поменять размер шрифта python dearpygui?

Tags: python, шрифты, dearpygui

Всем привет. Хочу поменять размер дефолтного шрифта на `dearpygui`. В [документации](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/fonts.html) по этому поводу ничего не нашёл. Единственное, что хоть как-то покрывает потребности - это

```
dpg.set_global_font_scale(1.1)
```

Но данный метод не меняет размер шрифта, а увеличивает масштаб букв, из-за этого качество становится очень "мыльным". Подскажите, как по-людски поменять размер?

P.S. Не рассматриваю варианты с установкой других шрифтов по типу

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("./LiteralRegular.otf", 18, default_font=True, tag="Default font") as f:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
```

У библиотеки есть базовый шрифт. Если не ошибаюсь, это ProggyClean, но размер у него всего 13px. Как сделать больше?

Comment: "Встроенный шрифт является растровым, и его нельзя масштабировать, не делая его размытым." https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/2156

Comment: @СергейКох большое спасибо, искал методы, а самый первый абзац просмотрел